# System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security

Tags: service, installation, securityexception

I am trying to install an application named: "SQLScheduler" from here: http://www.lazycoding.com/products.aspx
But when I install the service I get this error :

System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security

any help?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't an answer to the question itself, but stackoverflow won't let me comment on others' answers yet, and I wanted this information in here because it will be useful to people who may have found this post like I did, searching for this error.
The reason the BCL is throwing a Security Exception instead of a UnauthorizedAccessException is because what the non-admin security level is insufficient for is writing to the Application Event log, not for the installation in general.

And sorry this won't help you with your problem, Sherif, as there are clearly other issues when you're installing it even as Admin. I recommend trying Nicole's follow-up suggestion to contact the tool's provider.

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening during installation, you probably need to install as an admin user.  (The wrong exception type is being thrown by the BCL in this case.  It should be an UnauthorizedAccessException instead of a SecurityException.)

Comment: Thank you, I ran it as administrator but now it throws another exception :
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'filw:///C:\Windows\system32\SQLScheduler.WindowsService.exe' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

Comment: Have you tried the tool provider's recommendation to "Please Contact us if you have any questions or problems"?

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party here, but I had this same error and found your message.

I received it while trying to install my service via the InstallUtil program.  My solution was to run the command prompt with "Run As Administrator" and that did the trick.

Hope this helps someone.